# Horizontal scrolling by using Shift+mouse scroll

Tags: scroll

I've been trying to find a way to scroll horizontally by using shift+mouse scroll (mouse scroll alone would of course only scroll vertically), in any Windows (XP) application. Can anyone suggest a simple way to do this? I tried the software AutoHotKey, but none of the scripts that were meant to do that worked for me.

Thanks!

Comment: Would very much appreciate some suggestions, thanks!